# facebook actionscript graph api - using request_ids to retrieve users

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, facebook-graph-api

If I have used Facebook.ui() to allow the user to select a bunch of their friends, how can I use the returned request_ids array to access the friends /feeds please?

I've tried the following:

```
Facebook.ui("apprequests", { message:"select some friends" }, handleAppRequest, "iframe");
```

which allows the selection of friends to tell about the app. I then do the following:

```
private function handleAppRequest(result:Object):void
{
    Debug.logObject(result, this, "handleAppRequest");

    for (var i:int = 0; i < result.request_ids.length; i++)
    {
        var requestID:String = result.request_ids[i];
        Facebook.api("/" + requestID, handleRequestFriends); 
    }
}
```

to select the friends returned in the result object (which I think might be where I'm going wrong), and then this returns a fail:

```
private function handleRequestFriends(success:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    if (success) trace("success");
    else trace(fail);
}
```

Thanks in advance
ob

EDIT: (new users can't answer their own question)

Hey again Michiel

ah i got it

it should be the following:

```
Facebook.ui("apprequests", { message:"select some friends" }, handleAppRequest, "iframe");

private function handleAppRequest(result:Object):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < result.request_ids.length; i++)
    {
        var requestID:String = result.request_ids[i];
        Facebook.api("/" + requestID, handleRequestFriends); 
    }
}

private function handleRequestFriends(success:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    if (success)
    {
        var values:Object = 
        { 
            access_token:Facebook.getSession().accessToken,
            name:"This is my title",
            link:"http://example.com",
            picture:"http://example.com/facebook/facebooktutorial/canvas/images/icon-75x75.gif",
            caption:"this is a caption",
            message:"This is a test message on " + new Date().toString()
        };

        var friendID:String = success.to.id;
        Facebook.api("/" + friendID + "/feed", handleSubmitFeed, values, URLRequestMethod.POST);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.logObject(fail, this, "handleRequestFriends");
    }
}
```

One question tho - can i use the facebook friend selector and just return the results without the apprequest firing off to them?

thanks
ob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would again suggest that you use the params to send your access_token, like in your previous question :)

```
private function handleAppRequest(result:Object):void
{
    Debug.logObject(result, this, "handleAppRequest");

    for (var i:int = 0; i < result.request_ids.length; i++)
    {
        var requestID:String = result.request_ids[i];
        var _params:Object = new Object();
        _params.access_token = Facebook.getSession().accessToken;
        Facebook.api("/" + requestID, handleRequestFriends, _params, "GET"); 
    }
}
```

and i assume you are trying to get the user, because if you want to post to their feed, you should just use

```
var _params:Object = new Object();
_params.access_token = Facebook.getSession().accessToken;
_params.message = _message;
Facebook.api("/" + requestID + "/feed", handleRequestFriends, _params, "POST");
```

edit: btw: are you sure you are getting the right id's with this method? (haven't accessed friends list before, so i have no idea).

Comment: i've edited the original post to add the answer and also ask another question:One question tho - can i use the facebook friend selector and just return the results without the apprequest firing off to them?

Comment: i guess you could have an apprequest firing at them, but if you redirect it to a function that does nothing but store the friends in an array, it can do no harm i guess? or what is it you want to know exactly? :)

Comment: hmmm - the problem is that the call to Facebook.ui("apprequests") actually fires the event to the users for free so I can't stop that happening.

Comment: well yeah, it fires, but you don't have to catch that event now do you? :)

Comment: I think that by using Facebook.ui() to deal with it, Facebook is doing all of the work of collecting the users and sending notifications for me - i'm not actually the one implementing the app notification although I am using the return from the method to then add some functionality.